# Looking for a tool that Sync lookup table data as opposed with just creating INSERT statemenents

Tags: sql-server, deployment, sql-server-data-tools

I am using SSDT to create the data population scripts. SSDT creates one INSERT statement per each row in the table.

The problem is that some of the lookup data rows already exist in the target database. So the INSERT statements generate PK violation errors.

Also, some of the rows need update, not INSERT.

Is there any tool (hopefully free) that allow me Sync (or merge) the lookup data. Without the tool, my data population scripts will be quite challenging and time-consuming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Convert Table Contents into Merge Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489184/sql-server-convert-table-contents-into-merge-statement)

Comment: sp_generate_merge is a perfect tool and is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sp_generate_merge` to generate a script you put in your post-deploy script.

ed

Comment: It looks promising. If I use the INSERT statements to populate data into a #TempTable, can I use sp_generate_merge to populate the changes into the target production table?

Comment: More detail can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10529575/1497596) by [@Dan Nolan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266882/dan-nolan) who is the the author of [sp_generate_merge](https://github.com/readyroll/generate-sql-merge).

Answer (score 1):

If you use SSDT to populate a lookup table, don't use separate INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements, use MERGE instead:

```
merge into dbo.Colors as target 
using (
    values 

    --  Id  ,   Code        ,   Name                                

    (   1   ,   'RED'       ,   N'Red'      ),
    (   2   ,   'YELLOW'    ,   N'Yellow'   ),
    (   3   ,   'GREEN'     ,   N'Green'    ),  
    (   4   ,   'BLUE'      ,   N'Blue'     )           

)   as source (Id, Code, Name) on target.Id = source.Id

when matched then 
    update set 
        Code = source.Code  ,
        Name = source.Name  

when not matched by target then 
    insert (Id, Code, Name) 
    values (Id, Code, Name) 

when not matched by source then 
    delete;
```

Comment: The idea is great. I have more that 15 lookup tables to sync or populate. Are you suggesting to hand code all the merge statements?

Comment: The MERGE is the best solution for that task. We keep all our lookup table scripts in MERGE statements.

Comment: Hand coding many lookup tables with many rows in them seem impractical and it is not productive. Do you hand code all the merge statement?

Comment: If there are too many rows in your tables, but lookup tables are edited rearly, use sp_generate_merge (suggested by Ed Elliott) after each change to generate MERGE instead of hand coding. If the lookup tables are edited often and you need to sync it with target DB - you really have to consider using something else but SSDT. Possibly SSIS suits you better.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I marked the post that suggests sp_generate_merge since that is a working approach.  but I appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Data Compare from RedGate is one and available as a 30-day free trial. You can use the GUI ad-hoc or the command line interface to automate updates. The product is not without its faults, but it can be very useful.